# How to parse/query a static html page using java and httpclient

Tags: java, javascript, html, json, httpclient

Here is the Http Post request using the HttpClient API.This piece of code lets me fetch the entire page content in the raw html format.My requirement is to send some parameters to this method such that it fetches only required data(like in a database) in readable format.By 'readable' I mean without the html tags.I dont know if JSON has to be brought in here.
I went through JSoup , but it seems to be doing the job of a scraper.
So how should I proceed with the html content I currently have?

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www.elitmus.com/jobs";

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // add header
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sn", "C02G8416DRJM"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cn", ""));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locale", ""));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caller", ""));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num", "12345"));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
                                 response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

}

}

Comment: are you in charge of the thing that is receiving the http post? In other words can you choose what format to send the response back in? It seems that what you need is an RSS feed isn't it?

Comment: I am afraid I am not.The html content-type is text/javascript. The site is hosted in a web server , i have no control on.Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried passing a different 'accept' header? It's unlikely to work but it's worth a shot. Usually listing sites like this one have an RSS feed somewhere that you can consume, I've had a quick look but there doesn't seem to be one here. So it looks as if you're stuck with somehow parsing the HTML. As you mentioned JSoup is the usual way to programaticly process HTML. But you might try using XSLT (in reverse?) Or just write your own parser that reads the file one character at a time and fills up various buffers as it goes (that's all a DOM parser does anyway).

Comment: I just tried it (accept=application/rss+xml).. it caused a 500 response. So you're back to scraping :(

Comment: oh well,thanks for trying. Let me write a parser then